# What does "cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable" mean in an nested array index?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

What does the error mean in this case:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    v[v[1]] = 999;
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:3:7
  |
3 |     v[v[1]] = 999;
  |     --^----
  |     | |
  |     | immutable borrow occurs here
  |     mutable borrow occurs here
  |     mutable borrow later used here
```

I found that indexing is implemented via the `Index` and `IndexMut` traits and that `v[1]` is syntactic sugar for `*v.index(1)`. Equipped with this knowledge, I tried to run the following code:

```
use std::ops::{Index, IndexMut};

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<usize> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    *v.index_mut(*v.index(1)) = 999;
}
```

To my surprise, this works flawlessly! Why doesn't the first snippet work, but the second one does? The way I understand the documentation, they should be equivalent, but this obviously isn't the case.

Comment: Learning Rust with Advent of Code? Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for the great question!

Comment: Precisely ; ) This is my 3rd year of doing it (2x Haskell before that) ~> thought to give Rust a whirl since I've started to be more interested in low level stuff

Comment: @LucasBoucke That's funny, I usually use Rust for my project, but I write this AoC in Haskell. They both are great languages in their domain.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The desugared version is slightly different than what you have. The line

```
v[v[1]] = 999;
```

actually desugars to

```
*IndexMut::index_mut(&mut v, *Index::index(&v, 1)) = 999;
```

This results in the same error message, but the annotations give a hint as to what's happening:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:7:48
  |
7 |     *IndexMut::index_mut(&mut v, *Index::index(&v, 1)) = 999;
  |      ------------------- ------                ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
  |      |                   |
  |      |                   mutable borrow occurs here
  |      mutable borrow later used by call
```

The important difference to your desugared version is the evaluation order. The arguments of a function call are evaluated left to right in the order listed, before actually making the function call. In this case this means that first `&mut v` is evaluated, mutably borrowing `v`. Next, `Index::index(&v, 1)` should be evaluated, but this is not possible – `v` is already mutably borrowed. Finally, the compiler shows that the mutable reference is still needed for the function call to `index_mut()`, so the mutable reference is still alive when the shared reference is attempted.

The version that actually compiles has a slightly different evaluation order.

```
*v.index_mut(*v.index(1)) = 999;
```

First, the function arguments to the method calls are evaluated left to right, i.e. `*v.index(1)` is evaluated first. This results in a `usize`, and the temporary shared borrow of `v` can be released again. Then, the receiver of `index_mut()` is evaluated, i.e. `v` is mutably borrowed. This works fine, since the shared borrow has already been finalised, and the whole expression passes the borrow checker.

Note that the version that compiles only does so since the introduction of "non-lexical lifetimes". In earlier versions of Rust, the shared borrow would live until the end of the expression and result in a similar error.

The cleanest solution in my opinion is to use a temporary variable:

```
let i = v[1];
v[i] = 999;
```

Comment: Woah! There's a lot going on here! Thanks for taking the time to explain! (interestingly those kinds of "quirks" make a language more interesting to me...).

Could you maybe also give a hint as to why `*v.index_mut(*v.index_mut(1)) = 999;` fails with "cannot borrow v as mutable more than once" ~> shouldn't the compiler be, as with `*v.index_mut(*v.index(1)) = 999;` able to figure out that the inner borrow is no longer needed?

Comment: @LucasBoucke Rust does have a few quirks that are sometimes a bit inconvenient, but in most cases the solution is rather simple, as in this case. The code is still quite readable, just a tiny bit _different_ than what you originally had, so in practice it's not a big deal.

Comment: @LucasBoucke Sorry, I didn't see your edit until now. The result of `*v.index(1)` is the _value_ stored at that index, and that value does not require to keep the borrow of `v` alive. The result of `*v.index_mut(1)`, on the other hand, is a _mutable place expression_ that could theoretically be assigned to, so it does keep the borrow alive. On the surface, it should be possible to teach the borrow checker that a place expression in value expression context can be treated as a value expression, so it's possible this will compile in some future version of Rust.

Comment: How about an RFC to desugar this to: `{ let index = *Index::index(&v, 1); let value = 999; *IndexMut::index_mut(&mut v, index) = value; }`

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I've got no idea how you'd formalize that, and I'm sure it's never gooing to fly. If you want to address this, the only way I see is by improvements to the borrow checker, e.g. making it detect that the mutable borrow can start at a later time, since it's not really needed that early. (This particular idea probably doesn't work either.)