# Multiple Mutable Borrows on one Line

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The following program is not allowed due to a violation of the borrow checking rules:

```rs
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&mut self, i: u8) { }
    fn baz(&mut self) -> u8 { 0 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo;
    
    foo.bar(foo.baz())
//  --------^^^^^^^^^-
//  |   |   |
//  |   |   second mutable borrow occurs here
//  |   first borrow later used by call
//  first mutable borrow occurs here
}
```

But you can work around this by binding to a temporary variable, like:

```rs
fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo;

    let t = foo.baz();
    foo.bar(t);
}
```

Why does the borrow checker start at the outer most function call? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: im voting to reopen this, it is absolutely not at all related to any of the linked "duplicates"

Comment: I feel that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59146116/442760) expains the same thing Chayim said with other words, take a close look at the desugared version and compare it to the desugared version of this problem. That the rightmost borrow of `self` is immutable in the linked question is of no consequence.

Comment: @cafce25 I don't understand, you can close a question when the answers are similar to others?

Comment: Yes, closure as duplicateis a way to direct people to an answer, since that answer applies here this question is a duplicate of the other. Having duplicates is fine, too, they serve as signposts so other people can find an answer more easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because Rust has a strictly defined [evaluation order](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order-of-operands), by which method arguments are evaluated left-to-right, and the receiver (`self`) is evaluated first. Evaluating the receiver includes evaluating any autoref/deref borrow for it, so the code is as if written:

```rust
let receiver = &mut foo;
let arg0 = foo.baz();
receiver.bar(arg0);
```

Here we can clearly see that `foo` is already borrowed when we call `baz()`.

Comment: ah, when you write it as `Foo::bar(&mut foo, Foo::baz(&mut foo))`, it makes perfect sense why the left-to-right eval order would get in the way of the borrows.